# How to combine two for loop in one for loop PHP

Tags: php

i want to combine two for loops

my first for loop:

```
for ($v = 1; $v<= $numvendors; $v++) {

}
```

$numvendors is equivalent to how many vendors i chose from 1 to 3

my 2nd for loop:

```
for ($a = 0; $a<= $count; $a++) {

}
```

$count is equivalent to number of colors displayed in vendor

For example in vendor 1 i have 3 colors on it

like this

```
Vendor 1

Color 1
Color 2
Color 3

Vendor 2

Color 1
Color 2
Color 3
```

I want to combine vendor number and color in one for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think so you can do it with only 1 loop for such task.. Except you also generated the ID of each row from database

Comment: You could have nested for loop. ie. color loop inside vendor loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($v = 1; $v <= $numvendors; $v++) {
    echo 'vendor' . $v;
    for ($a = 0; $a<= $count; $a++) {
        echo 'color',$a
    }
}
```

Comment: For echoing a simple String and variable combination, I'd suggest double quotes are easier to comprehend. For example `echo "Vendor $v";` would output as the OP wanted and is quicker to comprehend, meaning you don't make small mistakes like forgetting spaces.